# NSProgress fractionCompleted key-value observing method not called

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to track the progress of my HTTP request using AFNetworking and NSProgress. Basically, my request is a multi-part form data which contains text parameters, and image data, all in one block.

This is my code for the upload task, and it seems pretty simple and normal to me:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"<THE_API_URL>" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:constructionBlock];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

NSProgress *progress = [[NSProgress alloc] initWithParent:nil userInfo:nil];
[progress addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"fractionCompleted" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:&progress completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // UI reacts to error
    } else {
        // Do stuff here
    }
}];
[uploadTask resume];
```

Now, what I don't understand is that the callback observer method isn't getting called even though the upload task completes and succeeds. Can someone help me understand why? Here's my code.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];

    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"fractionCompleted"] && [object isKindOfClass:[NSProgress class]]) {
        NSProgress *progress = (NSProgress *)object;
        NSLog(@"Progress is: %f", progress.fractionCompleted);
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:** I followed AFNetworking's code for the `uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:...` method and found that they are actually replacing my `NSProgress` object from inside `uploadTaskWithTask:...`. Naturally, if the `NSProgress` pointer is made to point at a new instance, that new instance is not registered for observing the `fractionCompleted` property. How can I do key-value observing on this new `NSProgress` instance without modifying the AFNetworking code directly?

Comment: fractionCompleted is readonly, so my suspicion is that it is being computed when completedUnitCount is changed... all this meaning that fractionCompleted might be non-observable. Maybe if you try to observe completedUnitCount instead?

Comment: I'm afraid it is observable as stated in the NSProgress documentation: `Each of the properties of a progress object, including totalUnitCount, completedUnitCount, and fractionCompleted, support Key-Value Observing.`

Comment: @merlevede agree. I've looked into `AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate` sources. Code changes `completedUnitCount` property only.

Comment: I followed AFNetworking's code for the `uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:...` method and found that they are actually replacing my NSProgress object from inside `uploadTaskWithTask:...`. Naturally, if the NSProgress pointer is made to point at a new instance, that new instance is not registered for observing the `fractionCompleted` property. How can I do key-value observing on this new NSProgress instance without modifying the AFNetworking code directly?

Comment: If your original object is being replaced, which is a design that I never comforts me, there's not much you can do from a KVO point of view.

Comment: Gee, that sucks. So this method is bogus? Is there any other way I can track the progress? :(

Comment: if you setup KVO after you create the uploadTask then it will work fine. Creating the uploadTask creates a new NSProgress object which will discard the KVO on your original one

Comment: Your question actually helped me look at a problem a different way and solve something that I have been stuck on for a while: a full override of UIProgressView which can make normal use NSProgress (aka .observedProgress). Your question reminded me of the WWDC 2015 session on NSProgress and between WWDC breadcrumbs and your question, bam, I have **real** circular progress view  which can now do all sorts of drawing and animation based upon simply updating completedUnitCount  aka `theProgress.completedUnitCount += 1;` somewhere else in the code. I'd hit the up vote 10 times for you if I could.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I abandoned this method of keeping track of the progress from an `AFURLSessionManager`. Instead, I used a good old `AFHTTPRequestOperation`.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"THE_API_URL" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:constructionBlock];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager] HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // Do stuff here
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // Catch error
}];
[requestOperation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    double percentDone = (double)totalBytesWritten / (double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
    progressBlock(percentDone);
}];
[requestOperation start];
```

Comment: Thanks pal, I couldn't set af2 method worked. Neither kvo nor directly using af's progress view method didn't respond so I've switched to af1 way just like you and my problem has been resolved.

Comment: This causes problems if you have multiple downloads running on your manager.

KVO is the correct way to monitor progress for individual downloads

Answer (score 7):

Well all you need to do is move your observer to after upload task has been created and it is going to work like a charm.

```
NSProgress *progress;

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:&progress completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // UI reacts to error
    } else {
        // Do stuff here
    }
}];
[uploadTask resume];

[progress addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"fractionCompleted" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest: creates a new progress object and returns it. If you setup KVO before this call it will be discarded

Answer (score 1):

You may be running into this issue, https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1398, which is actually due to a design limitation in NSURLSession.  Towards the end of the discussion, you'll see a proposed workaround.  I'm using this workaround and observing "fractionCompleted" works fine for me.

-brian